# Double integral cos(y)

Tags: integration

I have no idea how to calculate this kind of double integral.

$\int_D \cos(y) ~dA$ where $D=\{ 0 \leq x \leq 2\pi,~ |y|\leq x \}$.

Any help with this?

---

*(added from now deleted answer)*

Okay,

I tried this $\int_{0}^{ 2\pi\ } \int_{0}^{\ x} \cos y \, dydx  = 0$

but it is wrong.

Comment: Please, show what you tried. People in this place like to see your efforts before they can help you. Also, use $\tt LaTeX$-MathJax.

Comment: Welcome and i seriously recommend you to read the faq to understand the norms of this site. Normally you write your attempted solution in the question.

Comment: The approach taken (at Don Antonio's suggestion) gives twice the integral shown (added from now-deleted Answer) by symmetry (cosine being even, as Don Antonio said).  But twice zero is...

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Since $\;|y|\le x\iff -x\le y\le x\;$ , as $\;\;x\ge 0\;$, this gives the following integration region in $\;\Bbb R^2\;$:

$$\int\int\limits_D\cos y\,dA=\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\int\limits_{-x}^x\cos y\;dydx=\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\left(\sin x-\sin(-x)\right)dx=\left.-2\cos x\right|_0^{2\pi}=0$$

which doesn't surprise since $\;\cos x\;$ , the original integrand, is being integrated on a symmetric interval around zero.

Comment: Me neither, @hardmath...yet I'm almost positive that was the original formulation and the OP perhaps changed within the first 5 minutes of having posted his question, so that it didn't get registered as "editing", and in the meanwhile I began trying to solve the question and didn't notice the change...or there wasn't any change and I just misread: go figure!

Comment: Anyway, thanks @hardmath. The question's now edited.

Comment: Thanks DonAntonio ! :) Now i got the right answer and it really was 0.